# How to consume Azure Fuction from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have created and published an Azure Function (HTTP Triggered) for a search functionality. When I type an ID in a search box and click on "Search", it should call the Azure Function and get the result back.

How to integrate the Azure Function with my Controller Action in .NETCore?

Comment: call it over http and retrieve the answer?

Comment: Yeah it is just an http call, using an `HttlClient` it should be straight forward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the example how you could call your azure function into the controller.

I have a simple azure function which return a name and email once its called. Let's see the below example:

```cs
public class InvokeAzureFunctionController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAsync()
        {
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage newRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:7071/api/FunctionForController");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(newRequest);

            dynamic responseResutls = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>();
            return responseResutls;
        }
    }
```

**Test Function For Controller Invocation:**

```cs
public static class FunctionForController
    {
        [FunctionName("FunctionForController")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            // parse query parameter
            string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
                .Value;

            if (name == null)
            {
                // Get request body
                dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                name = data?.name;
            }

            ContactInformation objContact = new ContactInformation();

            objContact.Name = "From Azure Function";
            objContact.Email = "fromazure@function.com";

            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objContact);
        }
    }
```

**Simple ContactInformation Class I have Used:**

```cs
   public class ContactInformation
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**PostMan Test:**

I have called the `controller action` from Post Man and its successfully return data from my local azure function through the `local controller action`. See the screen shot below:

[image]

Hope you understand. Just plug and play now.